# ESQL-> How to use SELECT statement to retrieve value from input XMLNSC?

Tags: xml, select, ibm-integration-bus, extended-sql

I need to access a specific XMLNSC value based on its name. I have an input xmlnsc that looks something like this

```xml
<Message>
    <Tags>
        <Name>ev1</Name>
       <Length>004</Length>
       <Value>0050</Value>
    </Tags>
</Message>
```

I am trying to access `<Value>`element by using `<Name>` element. That is my statement however I think is not correct.

```
SET OutputRoot.JSON.Data.records[i].userId = THE (SELECT ITEM FIELDVALUE (InputRoot.XMLNSC.Message.Tags.Value)
            FROM InputRoot.XMLNSC.Message.Tags
            WHERE InputRoot.XMLNSC.Message.Tags.Name = 'ev1');
```

I'm wondering what the right way to accomplish this in ESQL would be.Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your general approach is correct. I suggest that you simplify the scenario, and also use _user trace_ to see how the ESQL is being executed.

Answer (score 3):

I think I spotted your error. You need [] in the FROM clause.
This may work (not tested):

```
SET OutputRoot.JSON.Data.records[i].userId = THE (
        SELECT ITEM FIELDVALUE (tag.Value)
        FROM InputRoot.XMLNSC.Message.Tags[] AS tag
        WHERE tag.Name = 'ev1'
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

You only need THE and ITEM for simple types, like character, I suggest you this:

```
SET OutputRoot.JSON.Data.records[i].userId = THE(SELECT ITEM P.Value FROM InputRoot.XMLNSC.Message.Tags[] AS P 
            WHERE P.Name = 'ev1');
```

This returns, if exist, the value of 'Value', not a ROW. So check it.

Comment: Not sure that your statement is 100% correct. THE and ITEM both relate to LIST values. A LIST is allowed to contain complex members. Perhaps you mean that THE and ITEM are _usually_ used when selecting a simple type...but that's not what you said.

Comment: Well, in the IBM docs saids that  " ITEM  in conjunction with scalar expression an the THE function it can be used to create a SELECT query that returns a single scalar value". That's it.

Comment: Yes, I can see where the confusion arises. I think that sentence is describing one possible use of THE. In general, the THE function can be used on any list.